# Change field in nodeset xslt

Tags: php, xslt, symphony-cms

I have some xslt template witch applies an other one with nodeset. But I want to change one field there without retouching any others. Just an example code:

```
<xsl:variable name="item" select="menu-dish/entry/price -1" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="menu-dish"  mode="menu_dish_information"/>
```

Where menu-dish is my nodeset and $item is just my attempt to change price field in it. But the problem is that I can show the variable on a screen but it is only changed price field and with no other data and plus it is not a nodeset. I don't have a direct acess to xml because using somethin called Symphony CMS. So the idea is to pass all data to a template as it is changing price field. How can I do it?

Comment: You should be able to see the raw XML input by applying a stylesheet with only the [identity transform template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT). Once you have that, please post a [mcve] showing the input, an executable XSLT stylesheet (not snippets taken out of context) and the expected output.

Comment: This extension makes it easy to get the datasource XML: http://symphonyextensions.com/extensions/debugdevkit/

Comment: Thank you all guys for your help. But I actually found a solution. I am sending this field as a parameter to the template.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer.